# Can not understand java statement with new operator

Tags: java, new-operator

Normally, use `new ObjClass(args)` to create new object, how to understand this one?

```
    import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Mapper;
    ......
    Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
        public double f(double x, double y) {
            return 10 * Math.sin(x / 10) * Math.cos(y / 20) * x;
        }
    };
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Mapper` is a class, then it creates an anonymous class that extends it. If `Mapper` is a `final` class, then this code won't compile.

If `Mapper` is interface, then it creates an anonymous class that implements it.

More info:

- [The Java Tutorials: Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `anonymous` Mapper, which contains that one method.  This has the same result as defining a `MyCustomMapper extends/implements Mapper` containing that method.

The idea is that you use an `anonymous` class like this when you need a custom functionality that is relatively simple for one use case.  For example, you should NOT use this mapper in any  other class.

Answer (score 1):

This type of construct is called an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Example:

```
interface Mapper {
    public double f(double x, double y);
}

Mapper m = new Mapper() {
    @Override // this annotation is not mandatory, but good practice! 
    public double f(double x, double y) {
        return 10 * Math.sin(x / 10) * Math.cos(y / 20) * x;
    }
}
```

This would be the same as this:

```
public class MyMapper implements Mapper {
    @Override
    public double f(double x, double y) {
        return 10 * Math.sin(x / 10) * Math.cos(y / 20) * x;
    }
}

// and then constructing like this:
Mapper mapper = new MyMapper();
```

This concept/construct is handy if you want do something quick.

With Java 8 this type of things has been become even more simpler with [Lambda Expressions](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html):

```
Mapper mapper = () -> return 10 * Math.sin(x / 10) * Math.cos(y / 20) * x;
```

A good book about lambda expressions in Java 8: [Lambda Reference by Angelika Langer & Klaus Kreft](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Lambdas/LambdaReference.pre-release.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This construct defines an anonymous class extending the `Mapper` class and overriding its `f` method.

Normally, you would annotate the overriden method with `@Override` (starting with Java 6).

Answer (score 0):

This code creates an instance of an [anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) class derived from Mapper and creates/overrides method f